# Trying to write a file, why am I getting "str object is not callable"?

Tags: python

I'm attempting to make a Dungeons and Dragons like game in Python, but I seem to have hit a wall. Whenever I run this code

```
file.write("Name:" (str(Char2)))
```

It returns

> str object is not callable

Comment: You're missing a `+` and have an unnecessary set of parentheses, `file.write("Name:"+str(Char2)) `. As it stands your code is attempting to treat the string `"Name:"` as if it were a function

Answer (score 2):

You are using "file.write()" function. Inside parentheses you must put string. When you use  "Name:" (str(Char2)) the Pythton see "Name:" as a function.

In other words, try this:

```
file.write("Name:{}".format(str(Char2)))
```

If you would like understand more see 6.1.3. Format String Syntax in this link: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html